# Problem in accessing global in data flow even save main session is set to true

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESqMz.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCuGn.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP2kC.jpg)The problem you have encountered:
I got an error regarding access of the global variable "regr" in my project. the previously same program was executed successfully but now it shows an error which I have attached herewith.

What you expected to happen:
Even though "save main session is set to true", I am not able to access regr (Global one)

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting and a piece of your code where you declare and use this variable?

Comment: @Alexandre Moraes    I have attached the code and error snap.. kindly help me.

Comment: I need a piece of your code where you define your variable and where you use it. Can you share it ? Remember to hide sensitive info when you share it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `regr` looks to be defined in the function scope. Can you try defining it in the base scope like so:

```py
regr = None

class MyDoFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, elm):
    yield apply_operation(elm, regr)

def run(...):
  regr = calculate_regr()
  ...
  p.run().wait_until_finish()
```